# how to set preprocessor definition of _win32_wce in vs08

Tags: visual-studio-2008, winapi, visual-c++, preprocessor, windows-ce

How to set preprocessor defination in vs08.By default the value of _win32_wce is $(CEVER) set.but when I build the project the error "c1017 invalid integer constant expression" occur.and warning that environment variable $(CEVER) and $(ceplatform) not set.
but when I set it _win32_wce=0x0420 then the all errors removes.but its hard coded.I do't want to do such type.so what should be value of _win32_wce.
**Note** that my poject's earliar solution platform was

> PocketPC 2003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This macro : _WIN32_WCE is defined by you platform SDK, this should be defined as follows:

```
_WIN32_WCE=$(CEVER)
```

and those are inherited properties, do not define it by yourself.

I suppose you try to use it in Desktop compilations, you should always check if it is defined before use.