# '/fp:fast' and '/Za' not compatible Visual C++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-options

I am stuck with a problem in Visual 2008 SP1.

The compiler yields:

> '/fp:fast' and '/Za' are not compatible

The problem is that i did NOT use /Za in the properties.. so I don't get why there should be a conflict when the option isn't set.

here is the generated command line in my project properties :

```
/Od /I "..\..\..\..\..\tools\gsoap-soapcpp-2.7.6\src" /I "..\..\..\..\..\platform\vs2008\win32\gsoap-soapcpp-2.7.6\src"   
/D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D   
"_CONSOLE" /D "YY_NO_UNISTD_H" /D "_WIN32_WCE=0x700" /D "UNDER_CE" /D "WINCE" /D   
"DEBUG" /D "ARM" /D "_ARM_" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm /EHsc /MTd /fp:fast /GR-   
/Fo"Freescale i.MX53 QSB - WEC7 (ARMv4I)\Debug IMX53/" /Fd"Freescale i.MX53 QSB - WEC7   
(ARMv4I)\Debug IMX53/vc80.pdb" /W3 /nologo /c /TP /wd4996
```

As you can see, /fp:fast is set but not /Za.

Is there another option that might indirectly refer to /Za ?

After digging a bit more, i realised that the BuildLog.htm file was saying :

```
Creating temporary file "(...)\Freescale i.MX53 QSB - WEC7 (ARMv4I)\Debug IMX53\RSP00000341365424.rsp" with content  

[{CORRECT COMMAND LINE}

{list of source files paths}
]  

Creating command line "cl.exe @"(...)\Freescale i.MX53 QSB - WEC7 (ARMv4I)\Debug IMX53\RSP00000341365424.rsp" /nologo"
Creating temporary file "(...)\Freescale i.MX53 QSB - WEC7 (ARMv4I)\Debug IMX53\RSP00000441365424.rsp" with content
[  
{WRONG COMMAND LINE containing /Za}  
{list of source files paths}
]
Creating command line "cl.exe @"(...)\Freescale i.MX53 QSB - WEC7 (ARMv4I)\Debug IMX53\RSP00000441365424.rsp"/nologo"
```

Do you have any idea why this second temporary file might be created ? Is there a property I have to fix in my project ?

[EDIT] Thanks to Hans I figured out the problem. One of my files in the project had a different compiler option that I was unaware of which caused the problem. I found which one it was thanks to the buildlog.htm file

Comment: Wow. If I google that message with quotes, this question is the only result. For the record, I don't have a clue either. Good luck!

Comment: Try *explicitly* adding the `/Ze` switch.

Comment: I have just updated my first post with new information

Comment: The compiler is started more than once if the project has source files with different compile settings.

Comment: Ok this helped me! I don't know why but one specific source file had a different compiler option. Thanks

Comment: @HansPassant maybe you can add your comment as a solution so that I can mark my question as answered ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing the compiler getting started more than once is a strong hint to the source of the problem.  You probably have some source code files in the project that have /Za turned on individually.  A quick fix is to select all the files in the project with Shift+Click and resetting the option.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2008, Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Language, change "Disable Language Extensions" from "Yes(/Za)" to "No".

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are using the wrong version of WinCE for VS2008 - you appear to be compiling for ARM here, yes?  My suspicions are aroused by the reference to `vc80.pdb` which is on the face of it a VS2005 vintage symbol file. Maybe this is a VS2005 project that you are porting across?

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467546/how-to-set-preprocessor-defination-of-win32-wce-in-vs08) indicates you should not manually define `_WIN32_WCE`, you could try the suggestion it provides for correlating this to the correct Platform SDK definition.

Comment: Well, i don't define it manually. It is set to WIN32_WCE=$(CEVER) which is then processed as "_WIN32_WCE=0x700".
Concerning the vc80.pdb, yes my project is a project that was upgraded from 2005 to 2008.

Comment: I am afraid my input was a bit of a shot in the dark but seemed too big for a comment. Have you tried importing the code as a new project instead of upgrading? perhaps the upgrade process for this variant has one or more bugs. Is there any setting in the GUI project properties (or in the .vcproj file) that looks like it might be VS2005-y? eg. if you see 80 anywhere try changing it to 90 (after backing up the original). I wonder if you are somehow picking up a VS2005 library that is binary-incompatible with VS2008.

Comment: Well it seems it is not what was the problem but I might have to change it thought. Thanks